# Calling another api in firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Firbase functions, server, express.
I cannot make a call function which call outside https address. (egress ?)
This address is for test, and I need to call payment api.
Do I need to set VPS, or gcloud setting?
I use node express, and set CORS.

```
app.get('/test', async (_, res) => {
  console.log('test started');
  try {
    fetch('https://www.scrum.org/open-assessments')
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log('resp', resp);
        res.status(200).send(' OK ');
      });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you on paid or free plan?

Comment: Blaze plan. I got 500 err, which means the `try` failed..

Comment: Yes but what is in the `error` variable? Do you have more specific information about it? You should not need to get a VPS or set up CORS for outbound requests from your cloud function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The issue was solved with `node-fetch` .. I don't know why `fetch` doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved with node-fetch module..